# How to Call a remote script using Python by passing credentials

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to call a remote Powershell script using python.I need to execute the PS script as a different user.

```
import subprocess
import sys,time
p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe',r'\\ABC.com\D$\PyPowershellTest\HelloWorld.ps1'], stdout=sys.stdout)
time.sleep(10)
p.kill()
```

How to pass the credentials for accessing and executing the remote script from python ?

Comment: Are you wanting to run the remote command on the remote computer?

Comment: Pretty sure psexec is the only way to do this, and it'll have to be on the destination machine.

Comment: @lit the python script I am running from my desktop and the powershell script should be executed in a remote server let ABC.COM here.The PS script stored in D drive of ABC.COM and I can access the server using a specific account.How to pass those credentials from python ?

Comment: @ChinmayNayak - Just using popen() will not get the script to run on the remote machine. It could read the script from the remote machine, but it would be running on the machine. Does your HelloWorld.ps1 script contain an `Invoke-Command` specifying another `-ComputerName`?

Comment: @lit No ,the HelloWorld.ps1 don't have any Invoke-Command .Its just taking some values generated by python script and updating in a excel file which is present in same server where HelloWorld.ps1 is present.

Comment: Does the `HelloWorld.ps1` script reference the Excel file through a UNC filename? The code you have now will run PowerShell on your desktop, reading the .ps1 file from `ABC.COM`. It will not run the script on ABC.COM.

Comment: @lit Yes,the HelloWorld.ps1 script reference the Excel file through a UNC filename and I dont have access to UNC path from my desktop.To overcome this I tried to trigger it from ABC server which has access to it.

Comment: @ChinmayNayak - Can your desktop access the file when running as the user account you will specify? If not, you will need to use `Invoke-Command` to run the script on the server which can access the file?